# Get Last Inserted Id in Doctrine and Insert that Id to its child table

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I m inserting records in 2 related tables, when a record inserts in parent table, I get its last inserted id (which is working fine), but when I provide this id to its child table, it accepts it as Empty Value.

**Here is my Code :**

```
$obj_users = new Users();
$obj_users->setFirst_name('ABC');
$entityManager->persist($obj_users);
$entityManager->flush();
echo $USERID = $obj_users->getId_user(); //this is working fine



        $obj_serviceprovider = new ServiceProvider();
        $obj_serviceprovider->setUser($USERID); // here it goes empty

        $entityManager->persist($obj_serviceprovider);
        $entityManager->flush();
```

What is the problem with my code ?

Comment: is it really receiving $USERID? have you checked it?

Comment: Is its is receiving $USERID

Comment: if i provide hard coded value to $obj_serviceprovider->setUser(12312); it still doesnot perform insertion]

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$obj_users = new Users();
$obj_users->setFirst_name('ABC');
$entityManager->persist($obj_users);
$entityManager->flush();
echo $USERID = $obj_users->getId_user();

        $obj_serviceprovider = new ServiceProvider();
        $obj_serviceprovider->setUser($obj_users);

        $entityManager->persist($obj_serviceprovider);
        $entityManager->flush();
```

as doctrine stores the id but needs an object when defining the child of a relation

Comment: Not working, if i provide a custom value like : $obj_serviceprovider->setUser(12312); it still doesnot perform insertion

Comment: if a relation is defined between `Users` and `ServiceProvider` entityes then setUser() expects a parameter of type Users

Comment: can u giv me an example?

Comment: see the change i'v made to your code... $obj_serviceprovider->setUser($obj_users); haven't you noticed it? I didn't just repost your code

Comment: I did noticed it but its not working either, cz as i said if i provide a hard coded value like ..... $obj_serviceprovider->setUser(123);.... it still doesnt perform insertion

Comment: Read carefully http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html .. see what relation YOU have defined.. if it's correct and the code examples in the docs. Probablu there is something elese wrong in your code too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39710/discussion-between-code-hunter-and-udan)